# What is meant by $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, notation

I'm homelearning calculus and trying to decide whether the following statement is true or false:

> If $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lim_ {x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =0$,
>   then also $\lim_ {x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=0$, where $F$ is
>   primitive function to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I'm sure what is $C(\mathbb{R})$. Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: The set of continuous real functions.  See wikipedias page for [Function space - Functional Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C(\mathbb{R})$ typically denotes the space of continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. This can also be denoted by $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

$C(\Bbb R)=\{f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R: f\,\text{is continuous}\}$.